# How to create sites on an Azure App Service Environment

Tags: azure-web-app-service, app-service-environment, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I created an [Azure App Service Environment](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/microsoft/appserviceenvironment/) but when I opened up the App Service Environment blade I didn't see a way to create web apps on it.

How do you create web apps on App Service Environment?

Comment: There are details on creating a web app in an App Service Environment (ASE) here [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-how-to-create-a-web-app-in-an-ase/](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-how-to-create-a-web-app-in-an-ase/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create it the exact same way that you create regular websites. When you try to create a web app the App Service Environment shows up as an additional location in the Location blade.

Note that you'll have to create a new App Service Plan (previously called Web Hosting Plan) in order to change your location.

You can find full details on how to create it here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-how-to-create-a-web-app-in-an-ase/